# Bootstrap template Carousel images hidden in source

Tags: html, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to replace the current .jpgs in the carousel from a template I'm trying to use but I cannot seem to locate the images I wish to replace. Every carousel example I've seen has an obvious place to put the jpgs. My code from the template below does not. Any idea how the template carousel has 5 images without there being any visible .jpgs in the source? Thanks a bunch.

```
<div class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" id="myCarousel">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li class="active" data-slide-to="0" data-target="#myCarousel"></li>
        <li class="" data-slide-to="1" data-target="#myCarousel"></li>
        <li class="" data-slide-to="2" data-target="#myCarousel"></li>
        <li class="" data-slide-to="3" data-target="#myCarousel"></li>
        <li class="" data-slide-to="4" data-target="#myCarousel"></li>
    </ol>
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
        <div class="item active">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <h3>The Biggest <span>Sale</span></h3>
                    <p>Special for today</p><a class="hvr-outline-out button2" href="mens.html">Shop Now</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item item2">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <h3>Summer <span>Collection</span></h3>
                    <p>New Arrivals On Sale</p><a class="hvr-outline-out button2" href="mens.html">Shop Now</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item item3">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <h3>The Biggest <span>Sale</span></h3>
                    <p>Special for today</p><a class="hvr-outline-out button2" href="mens.html">Shop Now</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item item4">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <h3>Summer <span>Collection</span></h3>
                    <p>New Arrivals On Sale</p><a class="hvr-outline-out button2" href="mens.html">Shop Now</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item item5">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <h3>The Biggest <span>Sale</span></h3>
                    <p>Special for today</p><a class="hvr-outline-out button2" href="mens.html">Shop Now</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div><a class="left carousel-control" data-slide="prev" href="#myCarousel" role=
    "button"><span aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span> <span class=
    "sr-only">Previous</span></a> <a class="right carousel-control" data-slide="next" href=
    "#myCarousel" role="button"><span aria-hidden="true" class=
    "glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span> <span class="sr-only">Next</span></a>
</div>
```

Comment: They're being added with javascript by data-slide attribute

Comment: What's the site URL?

Comment: just testing on my own device. No URL at this time.